# nivo slider force next slide on navigation click

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, nivo-slider

I have the nivo slider working perfectly on a few sites.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade', 
        animSpeed: 1000, 
        pauseTime: 8000,
        controlNav: true,
        manualAdvance: false
        directionNav: false,
        controlNavThumbs: false

    });
});
```

Very happy, except for one thing...

When the slide transition is in process. I have to wait for it to complete before I can go to the next slide. This is a bad user experience if i have my slide transaition on 1 second. as it feels like a long wait if i want to click through quickly.

On other carousel banners, I can click through the nav buttons very quickly back and forth and the effect keeps up and dynamically changes direction.

Can't find anyone else asking this or a fix so assume I am missing something.  How can I have this effect with nivo slider?

You can see the same issue exists on the nivo slider demo http://demo.dev7studios.com/nivo-slider/ although it's difficult to notice as the images change shape so the navigation moves.

Thanks

EDIT: Added JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/micjam/Bq3nT/

Comment: Does it help any to change manualAdvance to true?

Comment: @elevine, no, i've tried toggling all the settings and had a look at the ones on the nivo site http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider